# Help with induction equation - please?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Use induction to show that the sum of the first $n$ power of $3$ is less than the new power:

$$\forall n \ge 1:\ 3^1 + 3^2 + \cdots + 3^n < 3^{n+1}$$

Make sure to show all steps of the inductive argument.

To be clear - I did not mean to ask that someone answer this for me - I thought the site was used for people to help you work through a problem? Not necessarily give me the answer?

I have struggled with inductions and do not understand the logic behind the steps, even reading examples from texts and other websites. I guess I would like someone to help explain the steps to me (in plain non-math saavy English?) so that I will be able to answer this question?

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend not to respond well to questions, like this, that look like routine homework problems and which show no effort at all.  What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Can you first prove this for the case n=1? Then assume it true for n-1 and using that prove it is true for n. Can you follow this? Or may be you can follow some example that they could've used in your book. See how the induction principle works.

Comment: As an aside, the result should be obvious when looking at the number written in base 3.  $1000>110$ and $10000>1110$ etc... you have $3^{n+1}$ will be an $n+2$ digit number in base 3 while $3+3^2+\dots+3^n$ will be an $n+1$ digit number in base 3.  All that remains is to formalize the argument as outlined in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a similar problem with a hint: Prove that $2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^n < 2^{n+1}$.

Hint: $2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^k + 2^{k+1} = (2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^k) + 2^{k+1} < (2^{k+1}) + 2^{k+1} = 2*2^{k+1} = 2^{k+2}$.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I don't understand how you moved the 2^(k+1) from the left of the < to the right? and how that equals 2*2^(k+1)....  
Trust that I have read notes and websites and examples on this & have no understanding how how or why these steps are executed.

I don't need it done for me but maybe you can use plain English to explain the steps of this example? I never meant for anyone to do it for me, previous questions I've seen show that people help one another. I apologize for not clarifying my intent?

Comment: @Rachel, see first prove for n=1. Here 2<4. Now assume the statement to be true for n=k. That is 2+2^2+...+2^k < 2^k+1. Now you have to prove it for n=k+1, that is you need to prove 2+2^2+...+2^k+2^k+1< 2^k+2. That's what he has written. But since we have assumed the statement to be true for n=k, (2+...+2^k)<2^k+1, there is already another 2^k+1 that gives you 2 times 2^k+1 which is 2^k+2. Now the proof is complete.

Comment: Exactly as Daniel Evans said

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to understand inequalities. It is typical, especially in real analysis, to replace smaller quantities by larger ones. I'll walk you through the induction step, as this is key.

> Suppose the assertion holds for all $n \leq k$. For $n = k+1$ we have the following:
>
> $$\sum_{j = 1}^{k+1} 3^j = 3^{k+1} + \sum_{j = 1}^k 3^j$$

Here we're just peeling off the $(k+1)$st term. This is common in induction arguments with sums.

> $$ \ldots < 3^{k+1} + 3^{k+1} $$

Now we're using the induction hypothesis. I can bound the sum of the first $k$ powers of $3$ by the next power of $3$. In doing this, replace the sum with $3^{k+1}$.

> $$ \ldots = 2(3^{k+1}) $$

Well, there's two of those things.

> $$ \ldots < 3^{k+2} $$

The trick: Two is smaller than three, so replace the two out front by a three. Well, $3 = 3^1$, and we get $3^{k+2}$, which is what we needed. Try to run through this yourself and get a cleaner write-up.